# SQL Join Statement based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

New SQL dev here. I'm writing a call log application for our Asterisk server. In one table (CDRLogs), I have the call logs from the phone system (src, dst, calldate, duration). In another table I have (Employees) I have empName, empExt, extStartDate extEndDate). I want to join the two together on src and empExt based on who was using a particular ext on the date of the call. One user per extension in a given time frame.

For example, we have had 3 different users sitting at x100 during the month of July. In the Employees table, I have recorded the dates each of these people started and ended their use of that ext. How do I get the join to reflect that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What are the datatypes for `calldate`, `extStartDate`, `extEndDate`?

Comment: @Declan_K MSSQL 2008. Calldate is datetime and extStartDate and extEndDate are smalldatetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM CDRLOGS A
INNER JOIN Employees B
  ON A.SRC = B.EmpExt
  AND A.CallDate between B.extStartDate and coalesce(B.extEndDate,getdate())
```

Please replace the * with relevant fields needed
and there may be a better way as a join on a between seems like it would possibly cause some overhead, but I can't think of a better way presently.

Comment: Be very carefull with `Between` on the date fields join. You can get errors depending on how the transition from one employee to another is handled.

Comment: Very true, I'm assuming the fields are date time and there is not any overlap; nor any voids

Comment: @xQbert That works for me to a degree. One litle hitch is that if a person is currently sitting at that ext (therefor the extenddate is empty) their matches do not get returned. How would I say something like "if extenddate = "" then extenddate = today"?

Comment: use coalese it will take the first non-null value in a series.

Comment: @xQbert That was it! I used COALESCE(b.extEndDate,GetDate()) and it reports correctly now. Thank you sir!

Comment: Please ensure your data falls under Declan_k's comment.  If you have voids or overlap you will get errant results.

Comment: @Declan_K Overlap will not be an issue. The same ext will not have a pwrson start or end on it on the same day. What does "void" mean in this context?

Comment: @souperGrover it means a call comes in to extension 1234 at 4:30:23 PM and an employee is at 1234 from 8:00:00 Am to 4:30:00PM ad employee 2 starts at 4:31:00PM  the "Void" of employee assigned would cause the call to not appear in the above query.